# How to add new line after and before method declarations in classes using prettier?

Tags: tslint, prettier, eslintrc

What settings need to be configured to add a new line before and after method declaration in classes in typescript files using [prettier plugin](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode) in vs code editor?

How can we achieve by writing any rule in `.prettierrc` or `tslint.json` file?

current behavior is

```
function one(){
// some code
}
function two(){
// some code
}
```

expected result

```
function one(){
// some code
}

function two(){
// some code
}
```

I have tried with below line in *tslint.json*

```
"lines-between-class-methods": "true"
```

but did not works

Answer (score 11):

What @lakshan mentions is an [ESLint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/lines-between-class-members). There is a TSLint rule that accomplishes what you are looking for but on in regards to class methods.

https://github.com/chinchiheather/tslint-lines-between-class-members

Run

`npm install --save-dev tslint-lines-between-class-members`

Add

`tslint.json`

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/tslint-lines-between-class-members"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "lines-between-class-members": true,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`lines-between-class-members` is a built-in of ESLint, the replacement of TSLint which is now deprecated. This rule works for both TypeScript and JavaScript and `--fix` is supported. See https://eslint.org/docs/rules/lines-between-class-members for full details. You probably want to set  [`exceptAfterSingleLine`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/lines-between-class-members#options) to true for TypeScript.

To make ESLint work for TypeScript you have to install npm packages `@typescript-eslint/parser` and `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` and include both parser and plugin in your ESLint config. See [typescript-eslint docs](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/README.md#configuration).

```json
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "lines-between-class-members": ["error", "always", { "exceptAfterSingleLine": true }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, inside your es-lint rules,

```
"lines-between-class-members" : ["error", "always"]
```

It will throw you an error if you violate the condition. & I think you must declare your functions inside a class in order that to work.

to add to that, you might not get auto-fix with prettier, because It turns out empty lines are very hard to automatically generate. The approach that Prettier takes is to preserve empty lines the way they were in the original source code.

Comment: does not help. I have  added to my `tslint.json`

Comment: I think that is an es-lint rule...not sure if it works in tslint.json. I could be wrong.